# Configuring snd-dummy on virtual Ubuntu machine

Tags: ubuntu, alsa

I'd like to install the `snd-dummy` driver on a virtual Ubuntu machine. I have the driver binary (see below) and the kernel has the `soundcore` module installed. I verified this with the `modinfo` command.

I've tried to use the `modprobe` command like this but get an error.

```
%modprobe snd-dummy
modprobe: FATAL: Module snd-dummy not found.
```

How can I tell the kernel to load the `snd-dummy` driver? Is there a configuration file that needs editing?

```
%uname -a
Linux ubuntu 3.13.0-129-generic #178-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 11 12:48:20 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Driver binary seems to be present.

```
%locate snd-dummy
/lib/modules/3.13.0-95-generic/kernel/sound/drivers/snd-dummy.ko
```

Kernel module `soundcore` is installed.

```
%modinfo soundcore
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-129-generic/kernel/sound/soundcore.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Alan Cox
description:    Core sound module
srcversion:     D85D01377883AF724850357
depends:
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-129-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        4B:73:11:88:5B:3D:E2:B1:8B:BD:C5:DB:5A:4C:EA:A0:F9:A9:AE:12
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
```

Module configuration for this ditro seems to be in

```
/etc/modprobe.d/
```

Comment: 1) Include real questions that you want to have answered. If you describe what you don't know, it is much more easy to guess wrong about what you want to get answered. 2) Format multiline "code" by selecting the lines and clicking `{}` 3) Don't include thanks or advanced appreciation of help (they don't contribute to the clarity of your post, they distract)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use `modprobe` :

```
modprobe snd-dummy
```

> modprobe - program to add and remove modules from the Linux Kernel

The located `snd-dummy` module is in `/lib/modules/3.13.0-95-generic/kernel/sound/drivers/snd-dummy.ko` instead of `/lib/modules/3.13.0-129-generic/kernel/sound/drivers/snd-dummy.ko`, that is why `modprobe` cannot find your module, it is in the wrong kernels directory.

Your module should be in `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/sound/drivers/`.

Comment: @JimmyNJ Updated answer.